# Accessing an async method from a Base Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

I have a .NET Core 2.2 Web Api project where I am trying to do everything using the async/await approach. I have a controller called "UserController".  I have methods in my "UserController" where I need to access the LoggedInUserId.  So, to accomplish this I created a "BaseController" which the "UserController" will inherit from.

**BaseController.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public int LoggedInUserId
    {
        get
        {
           Task<int> task = Task.Run(async () => await GetLoggedInUserId());
           return task.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a private method in the "BaseController" called "GetLoggedInUserId()" which will make a call into the database (which is why that method needs to be async) and retrieve the information I need.

So, after understanding that, here is my "UserController"

**UserController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    public UsersController() 
    {

    }

    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Create([FromBody] userCreate)
    {
        _userService.CreateUser(userCreate, LoggedInUserId);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am accessing the "LoggedInUserId" property from the "BaseController", but my concern is that because the "LoggedInUserId" property in the "BaseController" returns a "task.Result" that it is not truly asynchronous.

So, I thought of another way and that was to remove the "LoggedInUserId" property from the "BaseController" and make the "GetLoggedInUserId()" method a public method instead of a private one and access it as follows:

**UserController.cs**

```
_userService.CreateUser(userCreate, await GetLoggedInUserId());
```

So my questions are as follows:

1. Would both of these approaches be considered correct and do they both conform to the async/await way of doing things?
2. Do both of these approaches accomplish the same thing?
3. Are their any drawbacks to either of these two approaches?
4. If anyone sees any faults in these approaches can you suggest a better/cleaner way of accomplishing my objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple posts about what's wrong with this. Let's see how you could fix it:

```
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    public Task<int> LoggedInUserId()
    {
        return await GetLoggedInUserId();
    }
}
```

or just make GetLoggedInUserId() accesible. You get the point. And then:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Create([FromBody] userCreate)
{
     int loggedInUserId = await LoggedInUserId();
    _userService.CreateUser(userCreate, loggedInUserId);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Henk, that is exactly what I ended up doing.  But one question for you - Can I call the GetLoggedInUserId inline like this - _userService.CreateUser(userCreate, await GetLoggedInUserId()) instead of calling the GetLoggedInUserId() method outside?

Comment: Yes, easy to try. But that is purely cosmetic, I wouldn't mind the extra variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Would both of these approaches be considered correct and do they both conform to the async/await way of doing things?

No. Using `Task.Run` and `Result` are not using `async`/`await` as designed. The `Task.Run` part is superfluous.

> Do both of these approaches accomplish the same thing?

They both get the logged-in-user. However, the `Result`-based approach blocks a thread while doing so.

> Are their any drawbacks to either of these two approaches?

Yes. The `Result`-based approach blocks a thread, which limits your scalability.

---

It seems to me that there's a better way of doing this. I'm not fully familiar with the ASP.NET Core pipeline, but there should be a way to asynchronously handle authentication and get the logged-in user id before the controller is even constructed. Then you can expose it as a property, since by that time it is already loaded.

Comment: There is a better way, either through ASP.NET Core Identity if being used, or with a middleware

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Would both of these approaches be considered correct and do they both conform to the async/await way of doing things?

No, the first approach is not a correct one unless you have explicit reasons for using `Task.Result`, and even then, `Task.Run` is not required to call a method declared with `Task`.

> 2. Do both of these approaches accomplish the same thing?

No, the first method creates an unneeded Thread to synchronously block on it. If you were on a framework that uses a SynchronizationContext (think of classic ASP.NET, WinForms, Xamarin or WPF), you would face a deadlock. The second approach, however, is the correct way to do an asynchronous call. You would in both cases end up with the user id, for now at least.

> 3. Are their any drawbacks to either of these two approaches?

Yes, as mentioned above, the first approach only provokes a waste of resources.

> 4. If anyone sees any faults in these approaches can you suggest a better/cleaner way of accomplishing my objective.

Well, you didn't mention what are you using for authentication/authorization, but if you are using ASP.NET Core Identity, it already provides you with that functionality through the `UserManager<TUser>` class. Otherwise, you could use a middleware that reads the request and adds the data you need to the Controller.

Comment: Sorry, I am using IdentityServer for authentication.  So what you do not see in the code snippets that I sent is that I inject the "HttpContextAccessor" singleton service into the "BaseController".  From there, I grab the "HttpContext.User" object and grab the claims I need.  In my case I need the "sub" which I use to query my db to get my users' uniqueidentifier.  So from what you are saying is that i can do all of this asynchronously through either some custom middleware or a "UserManager<TUser>" class offered by identity server?

Comment: @BryMan No, Identity Server is an open-source product that runs on ASP.NET Core, but it is not ASP.NET Core Identity (which is a Microsoft product). You don't need `HttpContextAccesor` at all, though, that's only for classes that do not live in a request, while a Controller instance *always* lives in a request. You can just use (in an instance method) `var userId = User.Claims...`